# Sending two arrays via ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I want to post via ajax two arrays. One of them is multidimensional.

This is my code:

```
var values = $('.formularioempresa').serialize();
contactos = $('#agregarcontactos').data('contactos')[0];


            $.ajax({
                url: "forms/procesar_forms.php",
                type: "post",
                data: values+contactos,
                success: function(result){
                    if (result == '1')
                        $('#error').show(500).delay(3000).hide('slow');
                    else { 
                        $('#confirmacion').show(500).delay(3000).hide('slow');
                    }
                },
                error:function(){
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });
```

values is just an array of inputs and contactos is a multidimensional that comes from this piece of code (not exactly):

```
<form class="formulariocontacto">
<input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre[]" class="required form-control" />
<input type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido[]" class="required form-control" />
<input type="text" id="apellido2" name="apellido2[]" class="required form-control" />
<input type="text" id="telefonoc" name="telefonoc[]" class="required form-control" />
<input type="text" id="emailc" name="emailc[]" class="required form-control" />
<input type="text" id="cargo" name="cargo[]" class="required form-control" />
</form>
```

and the jQuery for this

```
var values = $('form#formulariocontacto :input').serialize();
$('#agregarcontactos').data('contactos',[]);
$('#agregarcontactos').data('contactos').push(values);
```

I obtain 2 arrays but I do not know how to combine it to post it via ajax.

Thank you for your help and sorry for my poor english :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to nest the arrays in an object:

```
data: {'values' : values, 'contactos' : contactos}
```

Of course that means both of these should actually be arrays. I'd recommend using [`serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) instead of `serialize`, and then you'll have arrays that can be cleanly nested like above.

```
var values = $('.formularioempresa').serializeArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put them in an array and use `join` with an `&` to combine them

```
data: [values,contactos].join('&'),
```